# Functional iteration of list of functions

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, iteration

I'm getting completely stumped on writing a function `makeIterate` that constructs an iterated structure out of a list of functions *e.g.* `{f, g, h}` and a list of corresponding arguments `{d1, d2, d3}` (same number of arguments).
More specifically, I would like the input

```
makeIterate[expr, {f, g, h}, {d1, d2, d3}, final]
```

have the following output

```
f[expr, {d1}, g[#, {d2}, h[#, {d3}, final] &] &]
```

The first function acts on `expr`, taking `d1` as the second argument.  Each subsequent function is to be inserted into the third argument.

The problem I'm running into here is that since the functions `{f, g, h}` themselves need to end up being inside a `Function` in the output, I'm having trouble disentangling the pure `Functions` that are supposed to be part of the output, and the `Functions` that are meant to be used in `makeIterate`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
makeIterateFunction[fns_, data_, final_] :=
  Fold[
    Function@@{#2[[1]][Slot@@{1}, {#2[[2]]}, #]}&
  , final
  , Reverse@Transpose@{fns, data}
  ]

makeIterate[expr_, fns_, data_, final_] :=
  makeIterateFunction[fns, data, final][expr]
```

So then:

```
makeIterateFunction[{f, g, h}, {d1, d2, d3}, final]

(* f[#, {d1}, g[#, {d2}, h[#, {d3}, final] &] &] & *)
```

and

```
makeIterate[expr, {f, g, h}, {d1, d2, d3}, final]

(* f[expr, {d1}, g[#, {d2}, h[#, {d3}, final] &] &] *)
```

This assumes that the arguments to `makeIterate` do not need to be held.  If this is not the case, then we must take more care to ensure that there are no evaluation leaks:

```
SetAttributes[{makeIterateFunction2, makeIterate2}, HoldAll]

makeIterateFunction2[fns_, data_, final_] :=
  Fold[
    Replace[{##}, {_[x_], _[f_, d_]} :> Hold[f[#, {d}, x]&]]&
  , Hold@final
  , Reverse@Thread@Hold[fns, data]
  ] // ReleaseHold

makeIterateFunction2[{f, g, h}, {d1, d2, d3}, final]

makeIterate2[expr_, fns_, data_, final_] :=
  makeIterateFunction2[fns, data, final][expr]
```

These functions give the same results as the originals except when the arguments are not inert.  Using a nonsense example for illustration, compare what happens when the original function is given non-inert arguments:

```
makeIterateFunction[{f, g, Abort[]}, {d1, d2, Abort[]}, Abort[]]

(* $Aborted *)
```

with the behaviour the updated function in the same conditions:

````
makeIterateFunction2[{f, g, Abort[]}, {d1, d2, Abort[]}, Abort[]]

(* f[#,{d1},g[#,{d2},Abort[][#,{Abort[]},Abort[]]&]&]& *)

```
````

Comment: Ah, so the trick is to put in a `List` before switching it out for `Function`.  That's how to avoid the dreaded `Function` clash